# reverting alpha numeric identity

Tags: sql-server, identity, alphanumeric

I see this question has been asked numerous times with rather good results, however this one differs in that we want to revert to a normal auto increment ID after we have added alpha numberic IDs.

We have 3 databases that will eventually all combine into a single database. In order for our system to remain compliant we need the IDs to persist over the merge. So far we have managed to combine the data in an alphanumeric fashion where we prefix the record ID with the database source, such as IDs that came from DBAA is now AA## and DBBB is now BB##.

The question now though, is it possible to revert the varchar ID column back to an auto increment integer without adding more columns or creating functions in the back end? The idea is that the next entry in the new merged DB will be one higher than the highest of the 3 DBs, so if AA10 was highest then the next entry would be 11. (with no prefix and no function in the back end)

```
CREATE TABLE tableTest
(
    colID varchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    [desc] varchar(10) NOT NULL
)   
ALTER TABLE tableTest ALTER COLUMN colID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1)
```

of course as you can imagine that didn't work. Ultimately I just want to know if this is even possible to do without back end functions or additional columns.

Comment: Think about this for a second. You have values like AA14 and you want to change the column to an int. That will never work. What you are describing is two pieces of information, a data source and a numeric value. Do NOT force these two pieces of information into a single column. That violates 1NF and causes untold amounts of pain. Instead, create two columns, one for each piece of information.

Comment: Also, if memory serves, you can't alter an existing column to an identity column

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is correct and I should have mentioned it previously. There was so much other logic problems I didn't even think about that subtlety. :)

Comment: I realize this is not the best way to go about this problem, but I work for a company that really wants it to be done this way. I've managed to redo the  ID field to be varchar so it handles the alpha portion and we can make it so the next value is what we are looking for, the tricky part is making it that way with no extra functions. Just give it straight, is this possible or not? and maybe if you have other ideas that would also be great :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to sum up Sean's and my comments - the answer is no.
This is impossible for many reasons.

You can manipulate the data in that column to create unique numeric values (that is providing your values are unique as is right now) - something like this will do the trick:

```
UPDATE tableTest
    SET colId = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(colId, 'AA', ''), 'BB', ''), 'CC', '') + 
    CASE 
        WHEN colId LIKE 'AA%' THEN '1'
        WHEN colId LIKE 'BB%' THEN '2'
        WHEN colId LIKE 'CC%' THEN '3'
    END
```

This way your current number part stays the most significant digits - so if your table contained values like
`.  AA1, BB5, CC7, AA30, BB12`, it will now contain these values:
`.    11,  52,  73,  301,  122` - as you can see, the "order" is preserved.

Another option is to add a new identity column, delete the current `colID` column, and rename the identity column to `colID`.
This can be achieved either by using ssms's table designer or by using `sp_rename`.
Note that if you are not using the table designer you will have to first drop the primary key constraint before you can drop the column.

Comment: yes the data is unique to begin with, of cause if you merge the 3 tables it will no longer be unique, what you have done there though does make sense and should work no problem. The goal is to preserve the IDs so creating a new colID sort of defeats the purpose. Unless the old IDs are also kept in its own column. Thanks for the help.